# How do I run a .jar file?

Tags: java

This is the hierarchy of files:

> desktop->Tic(folder)->contains: Game.jar  ;  Game (extracted folder)

Game (folder) has all .class files.

> Game.jar has META-INF->MANIFEST.MF->has Main-Class: Game.Main

So, how do I run the .jar file?

I looked at others' questions but couldn't figure out.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with using `java -jar Game.jar`?  You'll need to be in the same directory as the jar file

Answer (score 1):

If you have a manifest.mf file in Game.jar which points out Main-Class, you can run Game.jar by

```
java -jar Game.jar
```

or double click it on your desktop!

Another way to run Game.jar is

```
java -classpath Game.jar Game.Main
```

which does **NOT** require that the menifest.mf file exists in Game.jar.